# AVCaptureDevice - Setting whiteBalanceTemperature

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Using GPUImage but want to adjust the temperature on the camera before it comes into GPUImage.  From what I understand this is "illegal" but would rather just see it work and take my chances.

My code:

```
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] init];
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

AVCaptureDevice *device = stillCamera.inputCamera;

NSError *error;
if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
    [device setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked];
    [device performSelector:@selector(setWhiteBalanceTemperature:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9]];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing here

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
[device setWhiteBalanceMode:AVCaptureWhiteBalanceModeLocked];
```

and it will work. But only after a fashion—you'll find it very hard for any setting other than "very cool" to take, I suspect... (Not all Apple's private APIs work the way you might expect. Or, indeed, at all.